# What mechanism in the tidal effects around a black hole is it that destroys materia?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, space-travel

I just read this Quora question https://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-NASA-send-a-probe-into-a-black-hole-to-learn-more and although the basic premises for the question are flawed (travel time is prohibitive, you can't send out information from a black hole etc) several answers claim that the tidal forces would rip stuff apart. How is that possible?

The scale of a black hole is enormous and a spacecraft might be 10 or 100 m long - like comparing a grain of sand to the size of earth - how can the differences in gravity between two points just 10 meters away from each other be so big that it is ripped apart?

(I understand that the whole vehicle will be compressed into a very tiny "thing" whenever it "lands" on any object with high gravity.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect as an answer here. Your assumption is incorrect. The difference in gravity can be massive. As a little experiment, try standing in the middle of a fast spinning kids merry go round. Now try standing at the edge when spinning at the same speed. Centripetal force can be so powerful you may not be able to hold on. And that's only a difference of a metre or so...

Comment: Because the gravity gradient is very large!

Comment: There is a Q/A here (or perhaps in Astronomy SE) where I have discovered that if BH are massive enough tidal force gradient at the event horizon can be manageable by a body (ie less than the forces holding the body itself). That is because the EH is far from the centre. It makes sense even classically.

Comment: Also black holes don't have to be that big. The smallest stellar ones have a event horizon of 30km radius.